# How to get the value of Default.aspx textbox1 control into webusercontrol Textbox usig vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, webusercontrol

How to get the value of Default.aspx textbox1 control into webusercontrol  Textbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a public property in your usercontrol that you can access from your page.

For example(in your ascx):

```
 Public Property Text() As String
     Get
         Return Me.TextBox1.Text
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As String)
          Me.TextBox1.Text = value 
     End Set
 End Property
```

and in your Default.aspx:

```
MyUserControl.Text = "this is the text that should be in my usercontrol's textbox"
```

and the same to get the value:

```
Dim myUserControlsText as String = MyUserControl.Text
```

You could also set the Text [directly from the aspx-markup](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article16.aspx) of your page.

```
<uc1:MyUserControl id="MyUserControl1" Text="this is the text that should be in my usercontrol's textbox" runat="server" />
```